# How to Fix Blank Results when use for loop in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am Alvin and I was a beginner in C++ Programing Languange and I have a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    for (int i=0; i == 5; i++){
    cout << i << ", ";
      }

system("pause"); // i add this code to avoid program close when i try to run it
return 0;
}
```

and when I compile it doesn't display an error message i.e is successfully compiled but, when I try to run it, it's doesn't display 'i' values i.e it's display blank screen. can somebody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error in the loop test condition:

```
for (int i=0; i == 5; i++){  // the `==` will cause it to never enter the loop
```

should be:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 5; i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem not to understand the meaning of the entries in a C for-loop:

```
for (int i=0; i==5; i++)
```

Means:

```
Start with i being zero (i=0)
Continue the loop, AS LONG AS i equals 5 (i==5)
```

In other words, it does NOT mean:

```
...
Continue the loop, UNTIL i equals 5
```

Hence, you need to replace `i==5` by `i<=5`, because this means:

```
...
Continue the loop, AS LONG AS i is smaller or equal than 5 (i<=5)
```